# Insert data to parent table and child table at thesame time sql

Tags: sql-server

I'm want to insert data from parent table to child table with only one sql query.

I have two tables, the users table and the userInfo table

Users table - Parent table

- user_id - PK
- username
- password

UserInfo table - Child table

- user_id - FK to Parent table
- lastname
- firstname
  etc...

I'm using two INSERTs before to have same user_id. Is there any way to do it in a single query?

Comment: i think OUTPUT clause is ideal in this scenario.
are you inserting many record at a time.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a view with an instead of insert trigger. I'm not saying that's the best idea, but you could. Also, you could wrap this in a stored procedure to which you pass the username, password, first name, last name, etc and the proc will handle the two (or more) inserts for you.

Comment: thank you. I'm not sure how to do it, but I'll check some tutorials. Can you suggest where can I find a good tutorial for this?

Comment: Here's the documentation for CREATE TRIGGER: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a stored procedure that receives all the parameters needed would be suitable, you could try:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertAll @parameter1 parameterType, @parameter2 parameterType, @etc parameterType

AS

/*DO YOUR INSERTS HERE*/

GO
```

And then, to execute it:

```
EXEC sp_insertAll @parameter1 = value, @parameter2 = value, @etc = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SP and pass all the parameters.

e.g.,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_InsertMasterDetail

@param1 <datatype>

@param2 <datatype>

..................

@param1 <datatype>

AS

DECLARE @p_id int

--SETP 1 -- INSERT TO MASTER_TABLE
INSERT INTO MASTER_TABLE()
VALUES (..........)

SELECT @p_id= SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--STEP 2 -- INSERT TO DETAILS_TABLE
INSERT INTO DETAILS_TABLE()
VALUES(@p_id,.................)
```

And then execute it like,

```
EXEC SP_InsertMasterDetail param1,param2,param3,......
```